# Is it better to requestLocationUpdates in bursts with short intervals, or over a long period of time with long intervals?

Tags: android, performance, geolocation

I have an Android app that basically wants to track the user's movements throughout the day and report back to them each week with certain trends.  I initially thought that as long as the user had location services and/or GPS enabled, then the system was always trying to keep the user's location up to date.  However, after reading the article on [Location Strategies](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html), I realized that this is not the case.

It appears that, even though the user has checked the boxes for location services or GPS, the receivers only really attempt to determine the location of the device after an application calls requestLocationUpdates and will continue to do so until a call to removeUpdates.  (If this is not correct, please let me know).

Since my app really only needs a "rough" idea of the device's movements, I was thinking about only recording the location of the device once every five minutes or so.  However, neither of the examples in the article described this kind of application.  Both examples were more about determining the location of the device at a specific point in time rather than trying to "follow" the device around: tagging user-created content with the location at which it was created and locating nearby points of interest.

My question is, would it be more efficient to have my app "wake up" every five minutes and then use one of the techniques in the article to determine the device's current location (by beginning to listen, taking several samples, determining the best sample, stop listening, and go back to sleep), or would it be better to start listening for updates and give a minimum time between updates of five minutes and just never stop listening?

Answer (score 0):

Use a BroastcastReceiver to get new locations at regular intervals, even if your app isn't visible. Don't use a service, it might get killed.

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(MyLocationBroadcastReceiver.action), 0);
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5 * 60 * 1000, 100, pendingIntent);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5 * 60 * 1000, 100, pendingIntent);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER, 0, 0, pendingIntent);
```

Don't forget to add the action string to the manifest.xml, and to add the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission there (for GPS). If you don't want GPS, use ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION.

```
<receiver android:name="MyLocationBroadcastReceiver" android:process=":myLocationBroadcastReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="Hello.World.BroadcastReceiver.LOCATION_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

In BroastcastReceiver.onReceive(), you'll have to sort out what you get. I throw away new locations that have less distance to the previous location than the new accuracy. I also throw away "recent" locations if they have a significant worse accuracy than the previous one. And GPS fixes with accuracy higher than 100m are usually worthless. You'll have to store the locations in a file or in the preferences, because your BroastcastReceiver object won't exist between onReceive() calls.

```
public class MyLocationBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    static public final String action = "Hello.World.BroadcastReceiver.LOCATION_CHANGED";

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Location location = (Location) intent.getExtras().get(LocationManager.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED);
        if (location == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // your strategies here
    }
}
```